# RegExr with minimum 2 letter and optional letters, but no other letters?

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex for an text, that allow it, if atleast 1 word with 2 letters are inside, and minimum 25 letters or digits and also allow (0-9äöü,.' -), if other letters or digits there, it should be give an error.

---

Example:

correct:

- John Doe
- Max Müstermann
- John-Frank' Doe.

false:

- John/Doe

Regex:

- Wordregex:  ([a-z]{2})\w+
- allowed Items: [äöü0-9,.' -]
- max length: {25,999}

```php
if(preg_match("/([A-Za-z]{2})\w+/",$text)){
    if(!preg_match("/[a-zäöüA-ZÄÖÜ,.' -]/g",$text)){echo 'error';}
else{echo'error';}
```

I'm not sure how to get the solution in code.

Comment: The `.` shouldn't be `\.`?

Comment: In a character set the \ is optional for the dot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you might do is use a positive lookahead to assert the length of 25 - 999 and also assert that there are 2 consecutive `[a-z]`

Then match your character class `[a-zA-Z0-9äöü,.' -]+` with the allowed items adding a-z and A-Z to it.

```
^(?=.{25,999})(?=.*[a-z]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9äöü,.' -]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{25,999})` Positive lookahead, assert 25 - 99 characters
- `(?=.*[a-z]{2})` Positive lookahead, assert 2 times [a-z]
- `[a-zA-Z0-9äöü,.' -]+` Match any of the listed 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/12IdQa/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rK9TO)

For example (I have made the strings longer to account for the minimum length of 25)

```
$strings = [
    "This is a text with John Doe",
    "This is a text with Max Müstermann ",
    "This is a text withJohn-Frank' Doe.",
    "This is a text with John/Doejlkjkjlk",
];
$pattern = "/^(?=.{25,999})(?=.*[a-z]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9äöü,.' -]+$/";
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        echo "Ok ==> $string" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "error" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result

```
Ok ==> This is a text with John Doe
Ok ==> This is a text with Max Müstermann 
Ok ==> This is a text withJohn-Frank' Doe.
error
```

Comment: If u have more lines, it gives problems, but u can add an `\n` ! But why u have in the php code two times "[a-zA-Z0-9äöü,.' -]*" in the pattern?

Comment: @klediooo That was just another way of writing the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/YgD1ob/1) it without just a single lookahead. I have updated the answer with the initial pattern.